# Sending email using Express and Sendgrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendgrid

I am at the beginning and I know that this question may seem trivial. I created the homepage of my site (index.html) and inside it there is a form. I would like to be able to send an automatic email with the information to my email address every time the form is submitted.

To do this I used Node and Express but one thing is not clear to me. When I go to test the sending of the email, everything works correctly but the server is on port 5000 while the index.html page is on port 5500.

if I test the form on the following url --> localhost://5000 everything works correctly while if I test the form from the url relative to my index page --> localhost://5500 it redirects me to a default error 405 page.

I think there is an issue related to the path of express, someone could help me to modify my server.js file, in order to make the form works correctly (inside the index.html page).

Here is the code of the server.js file:

```js
// Send email after that form is submitted
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const router = express.Router();

// Import sendEmail function from utils/sendEmail
const sendEmail = require("./utils/sendEmail");

// Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// view engine setup
app.set("view engine", "html");

// Use Static folder
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/css/style.css")));
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/fonts/fonts.css")));

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/views/index.html"));
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});

//add the router
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 5500);

console.log("Running at Port 5500");

app.post("/sendemail", (req, res) => {
  const { nome, email, telefono, data, deadline, messaggio, budget, gdpr } =
    req.body;

  const from = "Irene@liberamente.site";
  const to = "irenetestarella.it@gmail.com";

  const subject = "Nuovo Prospect";

  const output = `
  <p> Un nuovo prospect ha appena compilato il form sul sito Liberamente </p>

  <h3>Dettagli prospect: </h3>
  <ul>
      <li>Nome: ${nome} </li>
      <li>Email: ${email} </li>
      <li>Telefono: ${telefono} </li>
      <li>Data ed ora preferita: ${data} </li>
      <li>Deadline: ${deadline} </li>
      <li>Messaggio: ${messaggio} </li>
      <li>Budget: ${budget} </li>
      <li>Consenso informato GDPR: ${gdpr} </li>
  </ul>
  `;

  sendEmail(to, from, subject, output);
  // res.redirect("/");
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure:[image: Folder]

server.js page [image: server.js]

index.html page [image: index.html]

Comment: can you try with just `app.listen(5500)` to see if it changes

Comment: I have tested and all works fine. The email arrives in my inbox. I think that I don't have explained well my problem. Where the server actually runs (I mean the url) is not the same of my index.html file (where is the form). I would like to set the path of Express point to index.html file. I added two screenshots to my post above: please see the url. The first is related to server.js and the second is from my index.html.

Comment: Your screenshots and your code all show that this is running on `localhost:5500`. I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: If I test the form from this URL localhost:5500 (first screenshot above) the form actually works fine but I would like to use the form from my index HTML file that is inside my "Views" folder (the URL on the second screenshot). When I test the form from my index HTML the form doesn't work and I am redirected to this URL http://127.0.0.1:5500/sendemail and an error 405 occurs. I am not sure but I think that there is an error on my server.js file. Something relative to the static assets or like that...

Comment: maybe it is a very simple question but someone can explain to me why if I text the form from the homepage of my site (localhost: 5500 / index.html) the form does not work while if I text from localhost: 5500 the form works correctly? Will the form work when I host the website?